# Select from Table A Rows that Contain Value from Column from Table B

Tags: sql

I want to `SELECT` from `TABLE A` all rows that Have Values from Table B Column 1.

Example:

```
Table A:
Name | AGE
Name1 19
Name2 50
Name3 50
Name4 51

Table B:
NAME | AnotherColumn
Name1 | ...
Name2 | ...
```

The result should be:

```
Name1
Name2
```

So Far I succeed to make the query but when I try to reffer on Value from Table B in the column it asks me to promnt that value.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @M. Ali gave me the correct answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A.Name
FROM TableA A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM TableB
              WHERE A.Name = TableB.Name)
```

OR

```
SELECT A.Name 
FROM TableA A 
INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.Name = B.Name
```